# WebSocketProxyException 403 when trying to submit image with praw on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, pythonanywhere, praw

I'm trying to use praw on pythonanywhere to natively upload an image to reddit.

[`praw.models.Subreddit.submit_image(title, image_path)`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.submit_image)

This works fine on my computer, but on pythonanywhere it throws a 403 error. (The image still gets uploaded though.)

I see [on pythonanywhere's website](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/403ForbiddenError/) that 403 errors are due to their proxy whitelist, but reddit is one of the whitelisted websites and praw uses `requests` which pythonanywhere says is a compatible library. Also the regular `submit` works fine.

```
File "/home/ibid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/subreddit.py", line 780, in submit_image
    return self._submit_media(data, timeout)
File "/home/ibid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/subreddit.py", line 494, in _submit_media
    response["json"]["data"]["websocket_url"], timeout=timeout
File "/home/ibid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 514, in create_connection
    websock.connect(url, **options)
File "/home/ibid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 223, in connect
    options.pop('socket', None))
File "/home/ibid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 122, in connect
    sock = _tunnel(sock, hostname, port, auth)
File "/home/ibid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 293, in _tunnel
    "failed CONNECT via proxy status: %r" % status)
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketProxyException: failed CONNECT via proxy status: 403
```

Comment: You should use a Python debugger to better recurse into the issue.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here.  That's interesting -- it looks like praw is using a WebSocket connection to upload the image, which is unusual.  The proxy that we use does support websockets, though, so I don't think that is the problem in itself. Perhaps the server they're using for websockets is a new one that we don't have whitelisted.

Could you try adding this just above the "websocket.create_connection" call at line 493 in /home/ibid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/subreddit.py:
print(response["json"]["data"]["websocket_url"])

...and let us know what it prints out?

Comment: @GilesThomas - I set a breakpoint there with pdb and ran the print statement. It returned `wss://ws-034ba158e876c2f4d.wss.redditmedia.com/rte_images/l5xwil1zcpb31?m=AQAAgrU0XXD2NGkZxPDPL3IGEISdU36B0eDHNZHzL-uXEQgL7vCQ` I'm guessing the problem is that "redditmedia.com" isn't whitelisted?

Comment: Thanks!  We've whitelisted the appropriate servers, just let us know via email if you're having any further problems.

Comment: @GilesThomas - Thanks, everything works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote the image-submit feature in PRAW. As is noted in [the documentation](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.submit_image), the Reddit API uses websockets when submitting images or videos through the API. This is different from how the API works for text or link submissions, which directly return the URL of the created post. When it comes to images and videos, the response is something like

```
{'json': {'data': {'user_submitted_page': 'https://www.reddit.com/user/username/submitted/',
                   'websocket_url': 'wss://ws-05ba9e4989f78959d.wss.redditmedia.com/rte_images/z4a98g21vsb31?m=AQAAHFs1XR-NRjAq9D4PPYA6SuDvFIMUGGv2Vpv5ePM2bLV6wf5o'},
          'errors': []}}
```

We then have to listen on the websocket URL to eventually get the url of the created post. If you're interested, the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blob/610d28aa0e8aec2b63ded5270ffbb87a35a7a4c4/praw/models/reddit/subreddit.py#L464-L504).

---

As you found, the websocket URLs (at least at the time of this answer) tend to be a subdomain of `*.wss.redditmedia.com`. `redditmedia.com` isn't on [the PythonAnywhere whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/) (though `reddit.com` itself is), so the connection fails.

I see a few solutions for you, given here with what I think is most ideal first:

1. Get [Giles Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32846/giles-thomas) (who left a comment) or someone else from PythonAnywhere to whitelist subdomains of `wss.redditmedia.com`.
2. In PRAW >=6.5.0, pass the parameter `without_websockets=True` to disable the use of websockets. As noted in [the documentation of `submit_image`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.submit_image), setting this to `True` means that you won't get a return value at all.
3. In PRAW <6.5.0, use a `try`-`except` block around every use of `submit_image`. As you discovered, the posts will still be created. However, you will not receive a `Submission` object as a return value because the websocket will fail.
4. Pay to upgrade to the non-whitelisted version of PythonAnywhere.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for those details!  That's whitelisted now.